# rest api testing with jasmine and axios

Tags: javascript, rest, unit-testing, jasmine, axios

https://blog.kuldeepkamboj.com/node-rest-api-testing-with-jasmine/
I'm already familiar with the above writing unit tests using the request package.

Currently attempting to write unit tests using Axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios.

There is no failure when running the spec, but I'm confident that my code is failing silently and its not actually checking the statuscode. The console.log(response) does not print anything either.

How can I fix this testcase and was there a better way to debug this?

```
describe('api exists', () => {

it('GET /info should return 200 response', (done) => {
    axios.get("https://somesite.com/info")
    .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response); <-- does not print out anything 
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200); 
    })
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to place done() inside the promise.

```
 describe('api exists', () => {

 it('GET /info should return 200 response', (done) => {
   axios.get("https://somesite.com/info")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response); 
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200); 
      done();
    })
 });
```

Hope this helps!